# Wiring beans during integration tests with embedded mongo

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, unit-testing, junit5

I am using spring-boot (2.2.7.RELEASE) with webflux for a small-ish rest service with mongodb. I have 2 repositories (`ARepository`, `BRepository`) implemented something like this:

```
@Repository
public interface ARepository extends ReactiveMongoRepository<DataDTO, Integer> {
}
```

I also have an extra service which is using these 2 and a ReactiveMongoTemplate instance. It's wired something like this:

```
@Slf4j
@Service
public class DefaultTheService implements TheService {
    private final ARepository aRepository;
    private final BRepository bRepository;
    private final ReactiveMongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

    @Autowired
    public DefaultTheService(ARepository aRepository, BRepository bRepository, ReactiveMongoTemplate mongoTemplate) {
        this.aRepository = aRepository;
        this.bRepository = bRepository;
        this.mongoTemplate = mongoTemplate;
    }
}
```

All is good, it works as it should, no problems there.

Now, I want to write some integration tests and I started like this:

```
@DataMongoTest
@Slf4j
class DefaultTheServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    private ARepository aRepository;

    @Autowired
    private BRepository bRepository;

    @Autowired
    private ReactiveMongoTemplate reactiveMongoTemplate;

    @Autowired
    private DefaultTheService defaultTheService;

    @Test
    void runTheMagicTest() {
        // empty body, I just want to see if everything wires up correctly.
    }
}
```

When I want to execute `runTheMagicTest` (junit5), I am always getting this error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'com.example.DefaultTheServiceTest': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'defaultTheService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.example.DefaultTheService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:643)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:130)

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.example.DefaultTheService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1716)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1272)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1226)
```

*! notice the bean name: DefaultTheService**Test**

Normally, I could maybe get away simply creating an instance of DefaultTheService before each test and then calling the methods I want to test, but I'd like to give it a try using spring.

If I simply remove the `private DefaultTheService defaultTheService` declaration - the test is "running". I am pretty sure I am missing something stupid and I am chasing my tail.

So, can someone ease my pain and point me to the (possibly?) obvious error I am making?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`@DataMongoTest`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/autoconfigure/data/mongo/DataMongoTest.html):

> Annotation that can be used for a MongoDB test that focuses **only** on MongoDB components.
>
> Using this annotation will disable full auto-configuration and instead apply only configuration relevant to MongoDB tests.

Try a [`@SpringBootTest`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/context/SpringBootTest.html) for a "full"/default application context instead.

For general information refer to:

- https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/testing.html#testing

For (auto-)configuration details & refinement to:

- https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.testing

---

... setting `@DataMongoTest(useDefaultFilters = false)` (+ fine tuning `include-/excludeFilters`) can also do the desired.

Comment: Indeed, you are right. For some reason I missed it. Also, it doesn't make much sense to have only repositories autowired - not sure how much benefit would you have only for testing them (in mongodb context).